# Error running Android Resource Manager when creating new Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to create a new android application project.

I do File -> New -> Android Application Project, go through the steps of choosing the launcher icon, activity type, etc. When I try to click finish on the last page I get the following error :

[image]

I have been able to run and make Android Projects with Eclipse in the past. Am I getting this error because I have not updated anything?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, I would update your Android SDK Manager with the latest updates, then use the help->Check for Updates in Eclipse to make sure everything is on the same page.  Close, then restart Eclipse and try building the project again.

Comment: You might have corrupted workspace as well, try with another one.